# why do excel published static html files have content type octet on Amazon s3?

Tags: excel, amazon-s3

I do enough programming to get into trouble. I wrote some excel VBA to publish selected ranges, charts etc to static web pages. When the destination is say iCloud and I later copy the file to an S3 bucket all is good, the file with extension .html is S3 type text/html. If i set the path in the macro to be the s3 bucket directly  (using Cloudberry to mount the bucket as a drive) then the content type is octet. I see no way to fix this in excel/vba, but I may be wrong. Is there some way to set it up on the S3 side? The via code in part is:

```
    outputfile = "X:\WebPublishedicloud\" & PageName & ".html"
    ' publish file
    If PubTyp = 1 Then
         With ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSourceSheet, _
        Filename:=outputfile, Sheet:=sheetname, _
        HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .publish
        .AutoRepublish = True
        End With
    ElseIf PubTyp = 5 Then
        With ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSourceChart, _
            Filename:=outputfile, Sheet:=sheetname, _
            HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
            .publish
            .AutoRepublish = True
        End With
    ElseIf PubTyp = 4 Then
        Set Pubrange = ActiveSheet.Range(Addr)
        PubrangeA = Pubrange.Address
        With ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
            Filename:=outputfile, Sheet:=sheetname, _
            Source:=Pubrange.Address, _
            HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
            .publish (True)
            .AutoRepublish = True
        End With`
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to look to Cloudberry for an explanation and solution.  The uploading utility is always responsible for setting the `Content-Type` value.  When no value is set, S3 uses its internal non-configurable default value, `binary/octet-stream`.  S3 never sets the value to anything else on its own, so any time you see another value, it was set during upload.

Comment: I thought I had read that these days  S3 sets content type based on file suffix? See for this comment from Github.v1.0.2 has just been published with support for content types.

The S3Upload task now attempts to auto-determine content type based on file extension, using the same data as the AWS SDK for .NET and AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio. To support custom use cases, we have also added a a new 'Content Type' parameter, listed in the Advanced configuration section, that allows a custom string to be set. Note that if the task parameter is used, it overrides detection based on file extension

Comment: *"The S3Upload task"*  as well as the also-mentioned .net SDK and Toolkit for Visual Studio are all client-side things.  S3 itself does no such magic.